# Compiling pthread statically

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads

```
 Ruler501SabayonVM Rationals # g++ -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
  -g -O0 -o obj/primitive --std=c++11 testcase.cpp -pthread
  && cd obj && ./primitive 8 

 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'  
 what():  Operation not permitted
 Aborted
```

I've noticed this error before with pthreads but I am linking with it so I didn't think I should have this error.

For a note I am running this program on a really old computer that I don't have the ability to install packages on so the glibc version doesn't support C++11 at all which I use for threading.

The testcase I'm getting this error with is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

void hello(){
    std::cout<< "Hello Concurrent World\n";
}
int main() {
    std::thread t(hello);
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: And `primitives.cpp` is......?? Your build looks fine - it's executing `./primitive 8` that's causing you a problem. But without knowing anything whatsoever about that program.... I can't help you.

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Nah, you added a URL to the question. Where is your [testcase](http://sscce.org) in the question please.

Comment: You're getting an `EPERM` errno from a system call. You can use `strace` to diagnose which system call is failing. At the minimum it may help determine what the problem could be.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t84pZJDU is the output of strace. I can't run it in gdb because when I do I get an illegal instruction error from mpirxxx.

Comment: You're still not getting it. This isn't a support helpdesk. Posting links to offsite resources may help _you_ get _your_ solution today, but questions here are supposed to form a longterm repository of knowledge and information. So if you can't make this question universally useful to some reproducible problem given _in the question itself_, then I'm afraid it's off-topic here.

Comment: I wrote and tried it with a simple testcase, the error is definitely in pthreads, I'll rerun strace on the testcase to see if I can see anything new there.

Comment: glibc has nothing to do with C++11 support

Comment: whatever it is I know that programs compiled off-site don't run on it if they use pthreads and other c++11 features.

Comment: Does linking with  `-Wl,--as-needed -pthread` help?

Comment: Doesn't seem to, I get the same error, looking at strace I can't find anything that seems to be causing it, it just has some brk's before it prints out the error message

Comment: The problem is that libpthread is not getting used, so the real `pthread_create` isn't linked in and your program is only calling the stub `pthread_create` in glibc, which returns `EPERM`

Comment: That's what I figured, but how do I fix that?

Comment: Try using `-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread
-Wl,--no-whole-archive` instead of `-pthread`

Comment: Getting the same error still

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60041/discussion-between-ruler501-and-jonathan-wakely).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that libpthread is not getting used, so the real `pthread_create` isn't linked in and your program is only calling the stub `pthread_create` in glibc, which returns `EPERM`

The solution is to force the linker to use all the symbols from libpthread, even if it thinks they aren't needed, which is done with:

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

(Note `-lpthread` not `-pthread`)

Comment: That has got to be the quickest post-to-accept time I've ever seen. 17 seconds!